# How do I use sets on the contents of my file to create a list of all the characters used in the file?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been struggling to use set to create a list of characters that came from the file.

> myFile = open("WaP.txt")
>
> > > set = ()

after this, I am simply lost.

Comment: Please post an example input/output as well as your attempt to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you declare set using `set()` . `set = ()` means you are creating a tuple with name set

```
myFile = open("WaP.txt")
s = set()
for line in myFile:
   for character in line:
       s.add(character)
l = list(s)    # from set to list
```